# Which binding to use wcf duplex c# to java?

Tags: c#, java, wcf, interop, duplex

I want a pub/sub wcf service in C# and I want to connect to it with a android java app.

If i make a WCF connection using webHttpBinding it can talk with my android device but webHttp is not duplex.

If i use wsDualBinding or netTcpBinding I have a duplex connection but I can not use Java (android).

Which binding do I need to use if I want duplex and interoperability?

Comment: If you look at the documentation it is possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx
and here: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/haroldcarr/archive/2009/04/metro_interoper.html
But how?